# Clear JTextField when mouse click using only MouseListener java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, mouselistener

I know how to clear JTextField by mouse click:

```
    JLabel jlab;

ButtonDemo() {
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("A button example");
    jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jfrm.setSize(500, 200);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
    JTextField jtf=new JTextField("enter text here");
    jtf.setName("jtf1");
    jfrm.add(jtf);
    jtf.addActionListener(this);
    jtf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            jtf.setText("");

        }

       });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ButtonDemo();
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

But I have to use MouseListener:

```
...
jtf.addMouseListener(new MListener());
...

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MListener implements MouseListener{

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("mouseClicked " + e.paramString()+"              e.getComponent().getName() -> "+e.getComponent().getName());

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
//        switch(e.getComponent().getName())){
//            case "jtf1": Here I need access to ButtonDemo jtf1 element ;
//        }

}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

}
```

How can I get an access to JTextField whis is located in ButtonDemo on JFrame? **Switch...case** I need there because there will more than one JTextField. 
Second question - Is this approach totally bad?

Comment: JTextField focus listener would work better in your case?

Comment: To clarify the above statement a GUI should be designed for both mouse and keyboard usage. So if the user "clicks"  or "tabs" to the text field, the text should be cleared. That is why you should be using a FocusListener.

Answer (score 1):

> Switch...case I need there because there will more than one JTextField. Second question - Is this approach totally bad?

Using a switch case in not the proper design:

1. If the processing is the same, then there is no need for the switch case, you just get the component and do the processing.

So using the FocusListener approach the basic code would be:

```
FocusListener fl = new FocusAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {
        JTextField component = (JTextField)e.getSource();
        component.setText("");
    }
};
...
textField1.add( fl );
textField2.add( fl );
...
```

The problem with this is that every time a text field gains focus the text will be cleared. You probably only want to clear the text if the default prompt "enter text here" is being displayed, which leads to the second approach

2. If you have different processing for each component then you should use a separate listener for each component.

So in this case you would create a common class that contains a parameter so you can customize the processing.

```
public class ClearTextPrompt extends FocusAdapter
{
    private String prompt;

    public ClearTextPrompt(String prompt)
    {
        this.prompt = prompt;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
    {
        JTextField textField = (JTextField)e.getSource();

        if (prompt.equals(textField.getText())
            textField.setText("");        
    }
}
```

Then you would use the class like:

```
textField1.addFocusListener( new ClearTextPrompt("Enter First Name") );
textField2.addFocusListener( new ClearTextPrompt("Enter Last Name") );
```

Or if you want to get fancy you can check out the [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) which implements this basic functionality and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting a name to each JTextField when you create it, like this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textfield.setName("text1");

// Later on the event controller
if (((JTextField) event.getSource().equals("text1")) {
    // Do any stuff here
}
```